# Sorting HTML table using javascript but retaining values of column 1

Tags: javascript, html

I got this code here on another thread. Am trying to sort my HTML table but don't want the first column to change values. It should remain constant.

I have tried the code in my application using loop to get me numbered values 1,2,...
The problem is my column number is sorted when i click the column(s) that have onclick functionality.

```
var people, asc1 = 1,
        asc2 = 1,
        asc3 = 1;
    window.onload = function () {
        people = document.getElementById("people");
    }

    function sort_table(tbody, col, asc)
{
var rows = tbody.rows;
var rlen = rows.length;
var arr = new Array();
var i, j, cells, clen;
// fill the array with values from the table
for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++)
{
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    clen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array();
  for(j = 0; j < clen; j++) { arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML; }
}
// sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
arr.sort(function(a, b)
{
    var retval=0;
    var fA=parseFloat(a[col]);
    var fB=parseFloat(b[col]);
    if(a[col] != b[col])
    {
        if((fA==a[col]) && (fB==b[col]) ){ retval=( fA > fB ) ? asc : 
-1*asc; } //numerical
        else { retval=(a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc;}
    }
    return retval;      
});
for(var rowidx=0;rowidx<rlen;rowidx++)
{
    for(var colidx=0;colidx<arr[rowidx].length;colidx++){ 
tbody.rows[rowidx].cells[colidx].innerHTML=arr[rowidx][colidx]; }
}
}
```

I dont want column 1 to be sorted when I sort the the rest of the columns.
the HTML code is here

```
   <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 
 1; 
asc3 = 1;">Name</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 
1; 
asc1 = 1;">Surname</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc1 = 
1; 
asc2 = 1;">Age</th>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] (preferable as snippet -> `<>` / Ctrl+M) so we have something to work with.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56393500/edit) your question instead of adding relevant information as comment. And have a look at the link I've posted on how to create a [mcve].